# How to retry in kafka with separate retry topics and exponentional backoff

Tags: spring-kafka

To implement Retry architecture in spring kafka ( kafka version 2.3.6) with backoffs.

**Requirement.**

1. Event is first published in `main-topic`.
2. If the processing fails, then its pushed to `retry-topic-2s` after 2s. This retry topic has a separate processing code as compared to the main topic (consequently have a different listener function).
3. If the processing fails in `retry-topic-2s`, then its pushed to `retry-topic-6s` after 6s. This retry topic has a separate processing code as compared to the previous retry topic.
4. Finally if processing fails, event is pushed to DLT (`dead-letter-topic`).

**Problem.**

1. How to push events into a custom topic with a delay ( without using Thread.sleep ).

I have tried ContainerCustomizer to direct messages to `retry-topic-2s` directly without and delay and applying retry backoffs in this topic. But this is not satisfying the requirement.

```
private ContainerCustomizer<String,String, ConcurrentMessageListenerContainer<String, String>> customizer(KafkaTemplate<String,String> template) {
        return container -> {
            ExponentialBackOff exponentialBackOff = new ExponentialBackOff(retryFixedBackoff, retryMultiplier);
            exponentialBackOff.setMaxElapsedTime(retryMaxElapsedTime);
            if (container.getContainerProperties().getTopics()[0].equals(callbackRetryTopic)) {
                container.setErrorHandler(new SeekToCurrentErrorHandler(
                        new DeadLetterPublishingRecoverer(template,
                                (cr, ex) -> new TopicPartition(callbackDeadLetterTopic, cr.partition())),
                        exponentialBackOff));

            }
        };
    }
```

Can someone help me with this usecase?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is non-trivial and is now supported natively by all supported versions of Spring for Apache Kafka. There is a lot of code involved in supporting this feature.

https://docs.spring.io/spring-kafka/docs/current/reference/html/#retry-topic

Comment: Hello GaryRussel . I have looked into Retryable topic. But the problem I am facing is that I want completely separate processing for my retry topics as compared to my main topic. Something like @DltHandler which is annotated on a separate method for handling DltTopic. I require a separate method to handle retry events. Thanks

Comment: You can set `autoStartup=false` and manually start just the main listener container; then add separate listeners for the retry topics. Or, simply make the listener delegate to the appropriate listener method based on the topic from which the record was received.